# echoing remote variable in unix

Tags: unix, scripting

I have two environments- DEV and DRT. My dev environment has .profile set and resolves some of the variables on login like e.g. echo $AI_MKS gives me out put of /home/myname/somedir. Now I am trying to access Dev env from DRT env using SSH and want to echo $AI_MKS but I get an empty space. Here is what I am using

$DRT> ssh dev 'echo $AI_MKS'
output:

$DRT> ssh dev 'echo \$AI_MKS'
output: $AI_MKS

Expected output:

output: /home/myname/somedir

Comment: Anyone has idea?

Comment: So far I have tried everything I found at stack, I'm not sure what is wrong am I doing? when I separately do $AI_MKS after simple ssh I get the exact value but have to do it this way

Comment: I was able to solve it, Thanks

Comment: To volunteer a guess anyway - AI_MKS wasn't defined?